# What is the advantage of DolphinDB’s database-based partitioning design?

Tags: hdfs, database-partitioning, dolphindb

Why are partitions based on databases rather than tables in DolphinDB?

What are the advantages of such a design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distributed tables within a database (with the same partitioning mechanism) are colocated. For example, if you have tables containing snapshots, quotes and trades stored in one database, you can perform distributed joins on these tables concurrently since they share the same schema, which incredibly improves the join performance.